Who has "decision-authority" about paper content: First author or the co-author with the higher academic rank?
When co-authoring a scientific paper, content-related disagreements often arise (e.g., which sections should be omitted due to space constraints). My question is: Who typically has the final "decision-making authority" in such cases—the first author (the one who has invested the most ideas, time and expertise) or the person with the higher academic rank (e.g., the PhD advisor)?
EDIT: Most voted answer so far "how they reach a compromise if there is no genuine agreement is up to the team" is self-evident and very general in a idealized setting. My question is if there is any "unwritten rule" or best practices in the real word ;-) It is also not about "formal" rules or "veto right" just about common academic practice.

It depends on the field. If you do independent research collaborating with your advisor, then you must reach a compromise. If you work in a field, as I do, where papers are products of the research group, and the head of the group is the advisor, then they ultimately have the say because they are responsible for their group's product.

No, there is no unwritten rule. People find their own way through these disagreements. In the background, though, there is this: if it comes to a showdown in a disagreement between a student and advisor, the advisor holds all the cards — the student needs the paper more than the advisor does.

@zx the most up voted answer is not an idealistic utopy but it's actually the almost-written academic standard, and the correct answer to your question. If any of the authors does not agree with the content of the paper, the paper should not be submitted. A single author can request that a paper is retracted. or that his name is removed from the contributors.

Other comments and answers seem to focus on academic practice so far, but from a legal point of view, it would depend on the jurisdiction and the circumstances (though I suspect that in most places, it would be illegal for any of the authors to publish the paper without agreement from the other). This would be more a question for https://law.stackexchange.com if you're interested in this angle.

You got the answer to the question you asked about "decision authority", and the answer you got is about the common academic practice: agreement among authors is the standard.
Everything else is about how that agreement is reached, and that is going to depend on the specific circumstances and the personalities involved. Advisors somewhat definitionally have more experience and so their students may defer to them; on the other hand, students may have more in-depth knowledge about the specific subject and are closer to the work so their advisor may defer to them. In either case, the best result is going to be one where the people disagreeing make their relative cases and some agreement can be reached. How stubborn each party might be should depend on the circumstances, as well: for example, is some omission unethical (for example, it misleads readers about how the work was conducted) or merely not strategically ideal (for example, less likely to be accepted by peer reviewers)?
If either party backs away prematurely and does not make their case to their coauthors because of some perceived "this is the unwritten rule", they're doing a disservice to those coauthors.
Similarly, any advisor who makes it impossible for their students to bring up these sorts of concerns and make their case is doing their students a disservice.

All authors have power of veto: if they can’t reach an agreement, the paper should not be submitted. How they reach a compromise if there is no genuine agreement is up to the team and in practise, depends on internal politics.

Even more, if you believe you can and should invoke some formal "ruling" to resolve a dispute with your academic supervisor you have much bigger fish to fry than whether to drop this or that other section from your manuscript.

Since unanimity is required, the answer to the question is "all of them". The consequence is that no unanimity means no paper.

@MaartenBuis True; although it costs a poor postdoc’s years of hardwork to get trashed just like that (just a personal experience) :)

Absolutely.  It's in no author's best interest to have a (legitimate) paper go unpublished

Of course officially it is all authors must agree. The question is, lets say it is you (the proverbial you) the PhD student or postdoc vs me the corresponding author faculty. Who loses at a stalemate? I have my PhD, and tenure, and many papers, and control over who gets paid off grants (if you are holding grant-related work hostage it is well within my rights to move the funding to someone else). That is not to say I would do this, nor have I had to, but it it something to keep in mind as you navigate an amicable outcome in publishing discussions (lets avoid disputes as that is negative).

@R1NaNo One of my students once insisted on getting his own way on a paper. It was his way or no paper, against a high ranking prof. In the end, he won. It helped that he won against one of my lab's collaborators (who, funnily enough we no longer collaborate with), rather than me, but still.

@R1NaNo I don't think it is about "winning" but about "convincing". In practice, the tenured full prof will generally "win" because they've got the experience what works and what doesn't. Their argument should generally carry more weight. It is, however, on them to explain the argument in a way that helps the others understand why their position is right.

This is not always true, particularly in large collaborations (e.g. LHC, anything with a spacecraft). In those cases, authors have the right not to have their name on a collaboration paper. This isn't always due to disputes: some members sign all the papers they are entitled to, some may only sign the papers they have direct participation or knowledge about.

@R1NaNo Who loses at a stalemate? Everybody loses, nobody wins, if there is a slatemate. Best case scenario, you publish a paper and ruin the relationships with all your collaborators.
